# How to avoid page breaking when printing long lists

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm doing some styling for a printable brochure on my client's site, which could potentially contain long unordered lists of information.

My issue is when printing in Firefox the entire `<UL>` will break on to a new page instead of it's children `<li>`'s splitting, which means it doesn't flow with other content on the page.

I've found the CSS property `page-break-inside` is only supported in Opera and IE8, does anyone know of an alternative to this property or another method that I can use to prevent the entire list breaking on to a new page.

Cheers!

**UPDATE [23.11.2011]:**
I was able to use a work around on my issue, as the printed document is generated in response to a user's selection so this page is only ever going to be print I (very reluctantly) pushed semantics aside and removed the UL and replaced LI's with DIVs, which break correctly. The question still stands though, for anyone with a similar issue but using the same HTML for print & screen.

I will reproduce the problem I was having and post the necessary HTML & CSS as soon as I can.

Comment: it's a pain, but pdf export ...

Comment: If you could post a sample html document to work against, that would aid testing potential answers.

Comment: What version of FF exactly? I'm using the latest and it splits the UL normally.

Comment: also have you tried applying the orphans or widows properties? they and page-break are supported in ff3.5+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider programmatically removing the UL tags for the print version. You should be able to get the LI elements to display the same with some styling.

JavaScript or even jQuery can handle this easily enough but I bet you could take care of this server side instead.

I know it's not technically valid HTML but sometimes you have to bend the rules when HTML/CSS doesn't offer you flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

Credit goes to [david walsh blog](http://davidwalsh.name/css-print-page-breaks)

```
@media screen {
  .page-break  { height:10px; background:url(page-break.gif) 0 center repeat-x; border-top:1px dotted #999; margin-bottom:13px; }
}
@media print {
  .page-break { height:0; page-break-before:always; margin:0; border-top:none; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used Google to find this solution - Just another resource at my disposal.  I'm not sure who cares what search engine I used, honestly.  I tested in every browser that I have installed (IE8, FF4, FF5, FF6, and FF8, Opera 11, and Safari 5) - worked in all of them.

Comment: @JoshStodola - it doesn't matter where the correct answer comes from if the source is credited and it helps the person asking the question.

Answer (score 4):

For slightly better browser support you could use this:

```
ul li {
  page-break-after: avoid;
  }
ul li:first-child {
  page-break-after: auto;
  }
```

Should work in IE7 too. But won't work in Firefox. Browsers just suck when it comes to printing.